# Why are my files not loading as desired in stringbuilder?

Tags: java

my code is like so

```
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cmd.exe /C start " + gameExecutable);
        if (gameExecutable == null) {
            OptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunGameButton, "Could not find game executable automatically.");
            return;
        }
                if(selectedFiles != null) {
                    for(File mods : selectedFiles)
                    sb.append(" -file ").append(mods.getName());
                }
            }
```

But, when loading my files (for example: file1.pk3, file2.wad, file3.wad, and file4.pk3), (and assuming the gameExecutable is "game.exe") it loads with the cmd params

```
game.exe -file "file1.pk3" "file2.wad" "file3.wad" "file4.pk3"
```

But the desired output to game.exe is

```
game.exe -file file1.pk3 -file file2.wad -file file3.wad -file file4.pk3
```

OR

```
game.exe -file "file1.pk3" -file "file2.wad" -file "file3.wad" -file "file4.pk3"
```

Why is it not loading in the desired way? How do I get it to load with the desired output?

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` and separate each command and parameter as individual elements. There could also be a relative reference issues depending on where the command is been executed and the program searches for content

Comment: Wouldn't that be a problem if I added more things to the stringbuilder? I should have noted I have about 14 other items in the stringbuilder.

Comment: It depends what is `selectedFiles`, doesn't it?

Comment: selectedFiles is the result of a JFileBrowser.

Comment: Use and array or List to build your basic command instead of a StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that `selectedFiles` is an array with just one `File` object, and the name of that object is:

```
"file1.pk3" "file2.wad" "file3.wad" "file4.pk3"
```

That would be a weird name, but is not invalid, and would explain the behaviour.

Could you replace your inner `for` by this:

```
for(File mods : selectedFiles)
{
    System.out.println("This is a single file: " + mods.getName());
    sb.append(" -file ").append(mods.getName());
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have never heard of JFileBrowser, but now that I see [its documentation](http://support.objecteering.com/objecteering6.1/help/us/j_libraries/dynamic_dialog_boxes/jfilebrowser_methods.htm) I see that its `get` method is declared as:

```
public String get ()
```

So, even if you select several files it would return a `String`, not an array of `Strings`, so if you did something like this:

```
File myFile = new File(browser.get())
```

then it would create a `File` with the weird name stated above.

Answer (score 0):

In short, i would recommend you try>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If "selectedFiles" is a collection, your code works:

```
for(File mods : selectedFiles)
    sb.append(" -file ").append(mods.getName());
```

I tried it and it works as you expect it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String selectedFiles[] = {"file1","file2","file3"};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("cmd.exe /C start " + "game.exe");
        for(String file : selectedFiles)
            sb.append(" -file ").append(file);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

cmd.exe /C start game.exe -file file1 -file file2 -file file3

Answer (score -1):

I fixed my problem., when adding   `System.out.println(sb.toString());` to the bottom. It's loading things as desired *when I put the files in the same directory as the gameExecutable*

Don't know why it's causing issues when they're not in the same location. But it works.